# error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Copying DLL..."

Tags: .net, c++, visual-studio

Visual studio is giving the error **PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Copying DLL...".** The console window includes the output: 'CopyDLL.cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Here is some background as to why I don't know about the tool which is copying. Someone left the company a year ago and forgot to check in their latest version of code for a MS Visual Studio 2008 project using C# and C+_. Now we need to fix the program, but can't find the code and I've been assigned with trying to clean the mess up.

Comment: I figured it out. The CopyDll.cmd file was missing. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check the Custom Build Step (Project Properties->Configuration Properties->Custom Build Step) for all of the projects and all of the files.

It may be easier to open the *.vcproj files in a text editor and check the  tags under individual files in the project. Look for any  tags that have a non-empty CommandLine attribute.

Comment: Viewing and editing the *.vcproj file worked for me.  Was unable to find the problem in the project's Properties dialog, no matter how hard I looked.

Answer (score 2):

Turn up the build output with Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run

Set MSBuild project build output verbosity to something higher than the default.  I'd step it up one level at a time because the highest level is pathologically verbose.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools->Options->Directories and add this…
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE

That should do the trick...

Answer (score 0):

I'd never noticed before, but every time you do a build, there's a line printed to the Output window that says:

> Build log was saved at "file://...

CTRL-clicking on that link will give a lot more detail about the build that failed.

In my case, I found 3 "copy" commands, with the wrong filename, which pointed me to the CommandLine attribute in the vsproj file, as suggested by Andrew Garrison.